# XML XPath utf-8 error with Java servlet?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I use the following code to read my xml file which contains utf-8 characters:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(dataFile);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");

InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
is.setEncoding("UTF-8");

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

If I run the above code in a console java application, everything is perfectly fine.
But, if I run that code in a servlet/jsp with tomcat 8, then I lost all the utf-8 characters.
In my servlet/jsp, I already did:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

In tomcat 8 server.xml file, I already set

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

What are possible causes of the problems?

Comment: The XML must contain `<?xml ... ?>` without `encoding=...` or with encoding="UTF-8"` too. Editing the XML, with validation in your IDE might show something too.

Comment: @JoopEggen: the header is not required and when it's missing, UTF-8 is assumed.

Comment: @JoachimSauer my formulation was wrong: I meant that when there is an XML header, it might contain a (wrong) encoding.

Comment: Try letting the XML parser do the decoding rather than doing it yourself: ie. give it the InputStream rather than the Reader derived by decoding the InputStream. I don't see any reason why this should make a difference; it's just something to try.

Answer (score 0):

There are some extra steps to try:

1. Try to define a charset filter class:

...

```
public void doFilter(
  ServletRequest request, 
  ServletResponse response, 
  FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    next.doFilter(request, response);
}

...
```

also add related filter mappings to the `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharsetFilter </filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The filter ensures that if a browser doesn't use UTF-8 then your filter will convert all requests on its own.

2. In case of using JSPs add the following line to the very top of the each page:

   ```
   <%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
   ```

or add the following lines to your `web.xml`:

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

Also adding this `<fmt:requestEncoding value="UTF-8" />` JSTL line to your JSP code could be a solution.

BTW, do not forget to restart your Tomcat instance after these manipulations.

Hope it helps.